# A type declaration-description in an Elixir file -- is it really? Or anything else?

Tags: elixir

I've seen this in an Elixir file:

```
 @type t :: %__MODULE__{
    var1:      String.t,
    var2:    String.t,
    var3:       String.t,
    var4:     map,
    var5:        integer,
    var6:        list
}
```

What is this, what's it for and what does it do?

Comment: This is an example of typespec - http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html

Comment: @PatNowak what's "String.t"? Where can I read about this "typeABC.t"

Comment: Please read this: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#notes

Answer (score 1):

> What is this

It is indeed a type specification or "typespec".  It defines a type that's named after the current module, and specifies that the type is a struct containing three strings (of the binary-based Elixir kind, not the string-based Erlang kind), one map, one integer, and one list.

> what's it for and what does it do?

Erlang and Elixir are normally dynamic languages with very little in the way of typechecking; while it's possible to define functions that accept specific types of arguments (e.g. by using guards and/or "pattern matching"), it's not nearly as rigid as with, say, Java.

However, the Erlang ecosystem has various tools (most notably, one called Dialyzer) that's able to detect things like mismatched types and other common causes of bugs.  One of the ways Dialyzer is able to infer what types of arguments a function should accept is by the programmer annotating one's function signatures and modules with type constraints; that way, if there are any function calls which might violate those constraints, Dialyzer can pick up on it and yell at the programmer to fix one's code.

Meanwhile, documentation systems can use these same type annotations as part of function/API documentation, immediately signalling to anyone reading that documentation what a given function expects in terms of argument types, as well as the expected type of its return value.

This is all done on the Erlang/Elixir side of things by adding attributes to modules; the `@type` attribute creates a new type specification, and the `@spec` attribute can use those type specifications to signal which types are expected as arguments or returned by the function.  These don't really influence the code at runtime or compile-time, but they do help when documenting your functions or static-checking your code.

Elixir's Getting Started guide has a [pretty decent primer on how to use typespecs in one's code](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html).